# Is fastlist missing in javolution 6.0.0

Tags: collections, javolution

Possibly daft question but is FastList missing from javolution 6.0.0, or am I doing something dumb?

Example code

```
import javolution.util.*;

public class Test {

    FastList<String> test;
    FastMap<String, String> test2;
}
```

FastMap resolves and compiles, FastList is an unknown class according to Netbeans.

The docs seem to imply that all collections are in javolution.util.* as per standard java, but is there a different import for FastList?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's gone, use `FastTable`. See [javolution.org/apidocs/](http://javolution.org/apidocs/) for the newest javadocs.

I haven't seen any announcement of the removal, there only has been a minor mention in the [dev-mailing list](https://java.net/projects/javolution/lists/dev/archive/2013-04/message/1):

> With the upcoming release 6.0 (snapshot available, official release
>   very soon), `FastList` is superseded by `FastTable`. The new `FastTable`
>   (fractal based implementation) has fast insertion/deletion speed at
>   random location (like `FastList`) and a very small memory footprint
>   (like the original `FastTable`). In other words, you should be able to
>   replace `FastList` with `FastTable` anywhere in  your code with similar or
>   better performance!